# Syslog not logging IBM Broker messages

Tags: aix, syslog, messagebroker, broker

In a AIX Server I’ve been trying to save my IBM Broker (version 8.0) logs, but they’re not getting logged at all. I’ve configured the syslog file using either tabs on the first space or simply separated the path/file and the facility “user” by spaces characters.

**syslog.conf**

```
user.info   /var/mqsi/info.log rotate  size 4m files 4
user.err    /var/mqsi/err.log  rotate  size 4m files 4
```

Also tried:

```
user.info /var/mqsi/info.log rotate  size 4m files 4
user.err /var/mqsi/err.log  rotate  size 4m files 4
```

Then run:

```
refresh -s syslogd
```

After that I waited a couple of hours an the files were still without any logs.

The info.log and err.log files have system & root permissions, as well as chmod 640 (write and read) configured.

Comment: Try this command to check syslog `logger -puser.info 'Test user.info'`

Comment: @ Zsigmond Lőrinczy thank your for your help! Syslog it's working because it logs other facilities but the problem it's with that one in specific, user.

Comment: I deeply regret I am not a clairvoyant, so I have to ask you: have you tried the command I suggested? Are the log-files in question still empty?